# CSS not loading in heroku Hartl Ch 10

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

I just finished chapter 10 of Hartl's tutorial, and my CSS is not loading in Heroku.

I have tried running $heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile

And changing files in my production.rb

```
 config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true
```

I also tried changing config.serve_static_assets to = true because of one suggestion, it didn't work.

My Pg gem is in production:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

There are also no errors in my heroku logs.

Any other ideas? My repository-- https://github.com/ajhausdorf/sample_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `rake assets:clean` each time before you run `rake assets:precompile`.  This will clear out the files from your last precompile.